# How to change tnsping Used parameter files?

Tags: oracle, tnsping

Write in cmd: `tnsping orcl`

Used parameter files:

```
~/product\11.2.0\client_1\network\admin\sqlnet.ora
```

I want to change ref folder.
client -> dbhome1

So, if 'Used parameter files' = "~/product\11.2.0\dbhome1\network\admin\sqlnet.ora"
play sqlplus.

Answer (score 2):

You have some choices here

1. set the ORACLE_HOME environment variable. By default we will look in ORACLE_HOME/network/admin, or
2. set the TNS_ADMIN environment variable. We will look there if it is set
3. Don't bother with tns entries. You can use  //hostname:port/service_name as the string when you connect

Answer (score 0):

`sqlnet.ora` does not contain a database alias.
`tnsnames.ora` contains database aliases.
If you want to change the `tnsnames.ora` file and take the contents of the file in another directory, then you can add one more method to the above methods.
Change the directory with the required tnsnames file.

```
cd product\11.2.0\dbhome1\network\admin\
tnsping tns_alias
or
sqlplus user/password@tns_alias
```

For example.
i have 2 ORACLE_HOME

```
 1) C:\Oracle\10.2.0\OAS\NETWORK\ADMIN
    
     Directory of C:\Oracle\10.2.0\OAS\NETWORK\ADMIN
    23.07.2020  19:15    <DIR>          .
    23.07.2020  19:15    <DIR>          ..
    23.07.2020  18:54               526 tnsnames.ora

    2) C:\Oracle\11.2.0\dbhome_1\NETWORK\ADMIN
    
     Directory of C:\Oracle\11.2.0\dbhome_1\NETWORK\ADMIN
    
    23.07.2020  19:14    <DIR>          .
    23.07.2020  19:14    <DIR>          ..
    21.07.2020  13:00               628 listener.ora
    21.07.2020  13:00               450 sqlnet.ora
    21.07.2020  13:06               547 tnsnames.ora
```

`C:\Oracle\11.2.0\dbhome_1\` is default `ORACLE_HOME`

```
C:\Oracle\10.2.0\OAS\NETWORK>tnsping nbd11

TNS Ping Utility for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production on 23-JUL-2020 19:23:19

Copyright (c) 1997, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Used parameter files:
C:\oracle\11.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\sqlnet.ora


Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 172.26.32.175)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = nbd11)))
OK (20 msec)
```

`tnsping` work fine. it takes the database aliases from the file `C:\Oracle\11.2.0\dbhome_1\NETWORK\ADMIN\tnsnames.ora`.

`tnsping` Failed to resolve name.

```
C:\Oracle\10.2.0\OAS\NETWORK>tnsping nbd111

TNS Ping Utility for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production on 23-JUL-2020 19:27:51

Copyright (c) 1997, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Used parameter files:
C:\oracle\11.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\sqlnet.ora

TNS-03505: Failed to resolve name
```

Change the directory with the required tnsnames file.
`tnsping` work fine. it takes the database aliases from the file `tnsnames.ora` in the current directory.

```
C:\Oracle\10.2.0\OAS\NETWORK>cd admin

C:\Oracle\10.2.0\OAS\NETWORK\ADMIN>tnsping nbd111

TNS Ping Utility for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production on 23-JUL-2020 19:29:21

Copyright (c) 1997, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Used parameter files:
C:\oracle\11.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\sqlnet.ora


Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 172.26.32.175)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = nbd11)))
OK (30 msec)
```

For example 2.

Using the full address without using the tnsnames file.

```
C:\Oracle\10.2.0\OAS\NETWORK>tnsping (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=172.26.32.175)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=nbd11)))

TNS Ping Utility for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production on 23-JUL-2020 19:38:39

Copyright (c) 1997, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=172.26.32.175)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=nbd11)))
OK (20 msec)
```